# Reuse MySQL result in subsequent queries that have form SELECT DISTINCT from($result) WHERE, ?possible

Tags: php, mysql

I have a very complex query that basically gives me a master table of distinct combinations of various columns from multiple tables in my database, call it $query (using PHP), the $result = the result of the mysql_query.  I'd like to be able to reuse that $result in subsequent smaller queries without having to perform the really complex query again.

Something like SELECT DISTINCT column from $result WHERE xxx AND xxx AND xxx.  It works find if I actually put in the string for $result in, but it seems like it could be more efficient if it did not have to perform the whole complex query overtime.  Is that possible ?

Comment: It should simply be a matter of not changing the variable you stored it in. If you attempt to write the code first, and then in the event of any problems post the code and any errors, we can offer more constructive feedback.

Comment: If you are really using `mysql_query()` you should consider migrating to `mysqli_` functions or `PDO`. The `mysql_` functions were deprecated quite a while ago and have been removed in PHP 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either:

1. Save your results into a temporary table:

   ```sql
   CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE myTempTable SELECT ...
   ```

   Then use that:

   ```sql
   SELECT DISTINCT column FROM myTempTable WHERE xxx AND xxx AND xxx
   ```

or

2. Use a [view](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/views.html):

   ```sql
   CREATE VIEW myView SELECT ...
   ```

   Then use that:

   ```sql
   SELECT DISTINCT column FROM myView WHERE xxx AND xxx AND xxx
   ```

The difference is that views are visible across all sessions and will persist until manually dropped; whereas temporary tables are only visible within the session that created them (and therefore cease to exist when that session ends).

Also, views are exactly that: a *view* of the underlying data—thus when the underlying tables are updated, such changes will immediately be reflected when querying the view (except for normal transaction isolation behaviours).  By contrast, a temporary table (just like a normal table) holds a static copy of the data that will only be changed when explicitly updated by subsequent queries upon it.

Obviously there is therefore a performance difference: views can use the indexes of the underlying tables, whereas temporary tables must have their own defined.  But temporary tables use cached data and therefore do not have to rerun the underlying query each time (whereas views do).

Comment: Thanks.  I actually am using mysqli_query, thanks, typo.  

That is exactly what I needed to know.  I can imagine that there would be a large performance hit between views and temp tables if the query is complex, but the benefit is that views are dynamically updated and persistent., good to know.  In my case, I basically need to use the result for additional queries during the session, which could be a large number, and then I could destroy it or have it destroyed with the session.

Comment: @sscotti: With a temp table you can define indexes that will slow down its initial creation/population, but speed up subsequent retrieval; you can't do that with a view.  So which will be the most performant for you is very much dependent on your exact schema, data and queries—probably best to benchmark both approaches and see which you prefer.

Comment: Question about using Views.  Are those something you create in the MySQL engine and they persists, like are  creating a table.  So you don't create that programmatically within PHP ?  Kind of amazing if it has sort of a "listener" for changes in other tables and then updates itself automatically.  That good work also if the other tables are not updated very frequently during the session, in which case the View would be nearly static ?

Comment: Are there tools to perform benchmarks for queries during development so that you can actually measure which way performs better under various conditions ?

I've been using "Atom" recently, which is quite nice with a PHP Debugger tool in conjunction with XDebug, but I haven't seen MySQL tools for benchmarking.

Thanks.

Comment: @sscotti: Yes, views are created and persist in MySQL (though you create MySQL database objects by issuing DDL commands over the normal query interface—i.e. it can be done from PHP if you so wish, but it's not something you'd need to do every time a user visits a webpage because once defined it's there for good).  But they don't "listen" for changes: MySQL executes the underlying query each time you select from them, but it does it in a clever way (joining any further logic with the original query)—this is the big difference vs temporary tables, which simply store cached results.

Comment: @sscotti: MySQL comes with a load emulation tool, [mysqlslap](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysqlslap.html).

Comment: I think you need an AS, like CREATE VIEW body_hp_id AS . . .

Comment: One last question.  I  have subqueries in my complex query, so I can't create a single View from that, but apparently I can create Views from the subqueries and then create a temporary view on the fly when I need it.  That may work the best.  For now, I don't have that many rows, but at some point the temporary table could have 10,000 to 1,000,000 rows.  That could be a problem, although I've read that if you index the rows for the temporary table that can help, how would I do that ?

Comment: @sscotti: You can define indexes in the normal way when creating the table, eg `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE myTempTable ( PRIMARY KEY (cola), INDEX (colb, colc), INDEX (cold) ) SELECT ...`.